# Migrate old blogroll to menus automatically

Tags: menus

I have a very old installation of WordPress that I just recently updated to 4.9.4. It has a rather large collection of bloggroll links, which are displaying properly in the page. I'm now migrating this site to a site in a new 4.9.4 multisite installation.

I understand that the blogroll feature has been gone for quite some time, and has been (at least conceptually) replaced by the menus. I could create all the corresponding menu entries by hand, but I am talking about a rather sizeable collection of links.

Is there any way to export the links from the old installation and automatically import them as menus to the new one?

Comment: You can still use the links manager with new installs with the pre_option_link_manager_enabled filter.

Comment: @NathanJohnson Where do I go about adding this filter?

Comment: functions.php or there's a plugin at https://wordpress.org/plugins/link-manager/

Comment: @NathanJohnson Ok, understood, but, while that does enable the link manager itself on the new installation, it doesn't help me migrate the links from the old one...

Comment: The importer should still import links. I haven't tried personally in years though.

Comment: The importer might import links, or it might not. I have no way to tell, as the exporter itself didn't export them... Anyway, I ended up creating all 50+ links as menus by hand...